# Complex css menu

Tags: css

I have a menu:

```
<div class="headerMenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home <span>Home Page<span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About <span>About My Website<span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact <span>Get in touch<span></a></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My current CSS is as follow:

```
.headerMenu{
    width: 100%;
}

.headerMenu ul{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.headerMenu ul li{
    display: inline;
}

.headerMenu ul li a{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-left:50px;
    font-size:24pt;
}

.headerMenu ul li a:visited{
    color: white;
}

.headerMenu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current{
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../../Content/Images/menu-selector.png) repeat-x; /* 25x10 arrow/*
}
```

And now for the question:

1. How can i get the content in the span tag to be below the Main text.
2. When i hover over the `anchor`, How do i add the hover image as shown in screen shot

The Mockup i created in Photoshop looks like this:

[image]

I know this would be easily achievable by making use of images, but my solution requires that menu to be created dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) How can i get the content in the span tag to be below the Main text.

You need to use `display: block` on the `span` to have it appear on a new line:

```
.headerMenu ul li a span {
  display: block;
}
```

2) When i hover over the anchor, How do i add the hover image as shown in screen shot

Try to center the arrow to the top. This might work:

```
.headerMenu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current {
  color: #fff;
  background: url(../../Content/Images/menu-selector.png) no-repeat center top;
  display:block;
  /* also make sure that you use display block with correct height
   so that you can positionate the arrow on the correct place... */
}
```

Comment: I can't really solve it with the proper CSS anyways because I don't have the background images. And if he wants to learn it's much better if he tries to solve it himself rather than someone giving him the complete solution imo.

Comment: this works like a charm, i just had to romove the `display:block` style on the li:hover class

Comment: See Jason's answer, which includes a fiddle demo.

Comment: @Jared Yeah, it does. But that solution is not complete, as you can see in the results pane of the fiddle. Or maybe I'm missing something? I do believe that fiddle is good in situations where you are really showing a working demo. But in my case this code wouldn't work in a demo. But it might give him some ideas...

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code for problem 1:

```
.headerMenu ul li a span {
    display: block;
}
```

This sets the `<span>` to display as a block level element, therefore occupying the full parent container width by default.

For problem 2, there are multiple ways to do this. However, my suggestion would be to add the array to the `<li>` and use the `:hover` pseudo class. **Note:** that this will only work in IE for 7+.

```
.menu ul li:hover{
    background: url(../../Content/Images/menu-selector.png) repeat-x;
}
```

See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/kxqx8/1/ (I changed the colors to help display)